# How to loop over multiple tr's with *ngFor & *ngIf

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, ngfor, angular-ng-if

This sample of the template

```
<div *ngFor="let order of orders" class="col-1-4">    
  <tr *ngIf="order.user_id===user">

      <td> {{ order.package_id }} </td>
      <td> <img src="{{order.img}}" width="100" height="120"></td>
      <td>{{ order.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ order.price }}</td>
      <td>{{ order.size_i }}</td>
      <td>{{ order.size_s }}</td>
      <td>{{ order.color }}</td>
      <td>{{ order.count }}</td>
      <td>{{ order.order_date | date}}</td>
      <td>{{ order.price * cnt  | currency:'KRW' }}</td>

  </tr>
</div>
```

Comment: what have you tried ? give us more information on how your order object is

Comment: Hi Sangmin, please have a look on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to make sure that we can help you to solve your problem

Comment: sorry. it's my first Question. so, I'm not good at using stackoverflow yet.
but, I solved the problem, using ng-container!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `ng-container` will not render any html and the `tr` element will be visible if the `*ngIf` resolves to `true`

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let order of orders">
 <tr *ngIf="order.user_id===user">
      <td> {{ order.package_id }} </td>
      <td> <img src="{{order.img}}" width="100" height="120"></td>
      <td>{{ order.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ order.price }}</td>
      <td>{{ order.size_i }}</td>
      <td>{{ order.size_s }}</td>
      <td>{{ order.color }}</td>
      <td>{{ order.count }}</td>
      <td>{{ order.order_date | date}}</td>
      <td>{{ order.price * cnt  | currency:'KRW' }}</td>
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```